# One joomla to serve as multi-domain/multi-site with subdomains (vhost)?

Tags: redirect, multi-sites

I am trying to solve the requirement to move some parts of the website to subdomains.
But I do not want to split the website into multiple joomla instances

My first idea was to use 301 redirects for the specific pages. I configured the apache/nginx to serve the subdomains as aliases of the top level domain. So now I can access all pages with the main and all subdomains
  => ✅ done-check

My next step was to define 301 redirect for the parts of the page i want to have on subdomains
  => ✅ done-check

Now my issue is, that I have to control that all other parts of the domain have to stay on the top level domain.

I thought Virtual domain will help (https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22362/13241). But sadly the plugin does not do anything. So I got stuck with this approach.

What is the recommended way to handle my requirement?

Comment: Check also this extension: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mightysites/